# Text wrapping, css

Tags: html, css

Problem with text wrapping. Element ".usser a" doesn't wrap or if I use overflow in ".usser" this element overlaps div, and I don't see buttons.

[Wraping doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zs6u6.png)
[overflow in div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrLH5.png)

```css
.usser button {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.usser {
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  height: 25px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.usser a {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.usser div {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="employee" id="employee">
  <div id="list">
    <p id="1" class="usser">
      <a>xxx</a>
      <div>
        <button></button>
        <button></button>
      </div>
    </p>
```

Comment: Thanks. You might fix your truncated HTML and make this a snippet demo so we can all see the issue. Use the editor toolbar button.

Comment: `<p>` elements can't contain `<div>` elements. Invalid HTML

Comment: To close. Sory for problem. 
I swapped the order0" a" with "div" and threw the code from a to .usserer

Comment: j08691 
I don't know but it works already. I am doing it for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Just Use div tag instead of p Paragraph.

```css
.usser button {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.usser {
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  height: 25px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
.usser a {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.usser div {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="employee" id="employee">
  <div id="list">
    <div id="1" class="usser">
      <a>xxx</a>
      <div>
        <button></button>
        <button></button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I have already changed but they work and without it. It was necessary and reorder "a" with the button. All in all logical even.

Answer (score 0):

Ok Try this just add class to div tag in side paragraph testuvs & call in css

```css
.usser button {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.usser {
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  height: 25px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.usser a {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.testuvs {
  float: right;margin-top:-30px
}
```

```html
<div class="employee" id="employee">
  <div id="list">
    <p id="1" class="usser">
      <a>xxx</a>
      <div class="testuvs">
        <button> </button>
        <button> </button>
      </div>
    </p>
```